# Windows 7 Reinstalling Hardware - How...?

Tags: windows, drivers

I wanted to install a new driver for my Wireless Network Card but Windows 7 reported the driver was up to date. So I decided to uninstall the driver. That seemed to do more than I expected...

My WiFi card no longer shows up on the computer. Nothing in Device Manager. I have no idea how to get it back.

How can I get Windows to find the device? :/

Comment: Try to use the installation program from the driver disc or download the latest driver from the mfg and run its installation program.

Answer (score 1):

Try;

- Control Panel
- Hardware and Sound
- Add a device

This should start a search for devices not yet installed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should see the device in the Device Manager.

If you don't see it try:

1. open deive manager
2. Click at View in the Menu Bar
3. Click at show hidden devices

Then you also see desiabled/ignored devices or not plugged in devices.

If you still can't see the deice, check in the BIOS if the device is deactivated.

If you now find the device, open its Properties-Window and check what Windows reports as Device Status.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event that this guy is still waiting or in case anyone else wants to know how to add a missing device

Open Computer Manager, Click on Device Manager, in the centre pane right click on your computer name, select "Add Legacy Hardware", click next, select install hardware manually from a list, select wireless devices, next, select have disk, browse for driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to `Device Manager` ->Click on the *`computer name`*-> Click `Scan for Hardware Changes` in toolbar at the top of the screen. This will tell Windows to re-scan for any Plug n <strike>Pray</strike> Play devices attached your system, as well as any legacy items it previously detected

Comment: As a highly valued Super User, I suggest you revisit this answer and [add more detail](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users).